# How to retrieve a specific item with SPFx and Query in the React Framework SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, spfx, spfx-webparts, react

I would like to get a specific item by ID. I'm really stuck how I can retrieve this item.

I called the list and tried to save it in an object and then should in the render() function.

Here is my code so far:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './Webpartprojectsw.module.scss';
import { ISolypListItemState } from './ISolypListItemState';
import { IWebpartprojectswProps } from './IWebpartprojectswProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import * as jquery from 'jquery';
import { TextField, PrimaryButton } from '@fluentui/react';
import {ISPHttpClientOptions, SPHttpClient,SPHttpClientResponse} from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import { ISolypListItem } from './ISolypListItem';

  export default class Webpartprojectsw extends 
React.Component<IWebpartprojectswProps,ISolypListItemState> {

static websiteurl: string="";
public constructor(props:IWebpartprojectswProps, state: ISolypListItemState){
   super(props);
   this.state={
       status:"ready",
       SolypProjectItem:{
           Id: 0,
           Title: "",
           StartDate:"",
           EndDate:"",
           ProjectPhase:"",
           TrafficLight:""

       }
   };
Webpartprojectsw.websiteurl=this.props.websiteurl;
 };


 public componentDidMount(): void {
   let reactcontexthandler = this;
   console.log("Link zur Seite:" + Webpartprojectsw.websiteurl);
   jquery.ajax({
 url:`${Webpartprojectsw.websiteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProjectStatusList')/items(1)`,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {'Accept':'application/json;odata=verbose;'},
        success: function (resultData){
          console.log(resultData);
          reactcontexthandler.setState({
          SolypProjectItem: resultData.d.results[0]
          });
        },
        error: function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){

        }

   });

 }



public render(): React.ReactElement<IWebpartprojectswProps> {
return (
   <div>
     {this.state.SolypProjectItem.Title}
     {this.state.SolypProjectItem.StartDate}
     {this.state.SolypProjectItem.EndDate}
   </div>      
      
   );
  }

 }
```

Here is my interface:

```
export interface ISolypListItem{
Id: number;
Title: string;
StartDate: string;
EndDate: string;
ProjectPhase: string;
TrafficLight: string;
}
```

and my State:

```
import { ISolypListItem } from "./ISolypListItem";

export interface ISolypListItemState{
   status: string;
  SolypProjectItems: ISolypListItem[];
  SolypProjectItem: ISolypListItem;
}
```

I don't exactly how I can put the retrieved element into the object and then use in the HTML.

Comment: Are you getting correct results in `success` function of ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

When you are fetching a specific list item using `items(<item-id>)` endpoint you get the results in `resultData.d` instead of `resultData.d.results`.

For Example:

[image]

---

So, change your `success` function like this:

```
success: function (resultData) {
             reactcontexthandler.setState({
                 SolypProjectItem: resultData.d
             });
         },
```

Comment: That's great! I try to use this.

Comment: Is this working for you?

Comment: No, I get an error message that says that My variable is undefined:Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Id'). Do you have an idea where it is coming from?

Comment: Are you getting correct results in `resultData` variable? check by adding `console.log(resultData)`.

Comment: No. I only get a document object and not a "normal" result.d object

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? Can add a screenshot of resultData to your original question?

Comment: Nope. this time it's working fine and I only get one value. thanks

Comment: Hi @Matthias, can you please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? Your action on this thread will be greatly appreciated!